# EnableEurekaServer import doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, import, netflix-eureka

I build a Spring-Service with gradle and I wanted to use a Eureka-Server with it.
My java-file looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
public class Welcome {
   ....
}
```

but when I try to build it with my gradle-file it says:

> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server does not exist

I searched for a solution for this problem but I seem to be alone with it. Does someone know why it is not working? Do I have to write something specific into the build.gradle-file?

Comment: You have to add some dependency, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/61 and http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/#quick-start

Comment: Thank you for your help! The first link kind of helped me.
He used "compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:1.0.0.M2'" in his dependencies which didn't help me but after changing the M2 into an M3 it suddenly worked. Took me some time though to figure that out ^^

Answer (score 7):

The following dependency worked for me:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use a bill of materials to manage Spring Cloud dependencies:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Just add the following depedency to your project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

Spring Cloud releases have *names* instead of *numbers*. And you must ensure that Spring Cloud version is compatible with the Spring Boot version you are using. See more details [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/#release-trains).

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using gradle project, just add below dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this dependency worked for me.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have`spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server` added in your pom.xml file

```xml
<dependency>    
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```